# OWIN self host service permissions

Tags: c#, signalr, owin

I have a SignalR self host service(built on OWIN), when I run my service as local system user every thing works great, when I run it as our production "Special user" it does not work. The issue is whit the "Special user" permissions.

Is there a list of what permissions are need to run a OWINservice?

Comment: Binding to "http:\\domain:port" requires administration privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended-up doing is with a user with admin privileges is setting-up the port like this :

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://127.0.0.1:443/ user=myUser
```